# Event based model for polling a message from a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, polling

I have a linked list on which messages are stored. I would like to 'listen' to the linked-list and would want to process the message serially (one at a time , at its own pace). The point is, I do not want to poll for the messages in a infinite 'while' loop, unless you tell me it is fine. I think that is a in-efficient way of doing things. So basically I need a queue which behaves like a blocking queue at one end (receiver) i.e the linked list listener gets up only when message is posted on it. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: So, you want a blocking queue. I would thus use... a BlockingQueue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
blockingQueue.take()
```

You will need a different thread on the other side to take the messages and handle them